# Ausart Theme Option. I had installed a Theme but i have now this error:

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, wordpress-theming

I hope you can help me. I had installed a Theme but i have now this error, what can i do ?
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Method name must be a string in /Users/vkirov/sworkspace/payin7/payin7-blog/wp-content/themes/ausart/themeple_framework/system/view-gen.inc.php:319 Stack trace: #0 /Users/vkirov/sworkspace/payin7/payin7-blog/wp-content/themes/ausart/themeple_framework/system/view-gen.inc.php(51): themeple_viewgen->generate_element(Array) #1 /Users/vkirov/sworkspace/payin7/payin7-blog/wp-content/themes/ausart/themeple_framework/system/admin-pages-gen.inc.php(168): themeple_viewgen->generate_base_container(Array, 'active_section') #2 /Users/vkirov/sworkspace/payin7/payin7-blog/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): themeple_adminpages_gen->view_html('') #3 /Users/vkirov/sworkspace/payin7/payin7-blog/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #4 /Users/vkirov/sworkspace/payin7/payin7-blog/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 /Users/vkirov/sworkspace/payin7/payin7-blog/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action('toplevel_page_t...') #6 {main} thrown in /Users/vkirov/sworkspace/payin7/payin7-blog/wp-content/themes/ausart/themeple_framework/system/view-gen.inc.php on line 319
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the required php version installed in your server. Theme has a php version limit, any php newer than that (i suppose 5.6) can cause errors.